# How to check empty in my input text form with calculate?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 2 Input Text in my form how to fix calculate

```
<?php
$txtA="";
$txtB="";
$textA=0;
$textB=0;
$Total=0;

$txtA = $_POST["TextA"];
$txtB = $_POST["TextB"];

if(empty($txtA)){
    $textB=$txtB*0.4;
    $Total=$textB;
  
  if(empty($txtB)){
    $textA=$txtA*0.4;
    $Total=$textA;
  
  if(!empty($txtA) AND !empty($txtB)){
    $textA=$txtA*0.65;
  $textB=$txtB*0.35;
    $Total=$textA + $textB;
```

Always no data for this code i beginner in php and still learning

Comment: you may want to add your form to show how you send the data. check out this link it can help: https://www.texelate.co.uk/blog/how-to-test-for-empty-strings-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know if the value is setted, so we use isset($_POST['yourVariable'])

And you don't need to declare variables when your are defining them with $_POST value, with this said your code ends like this:

```
  <?PHP
  $Total=0;

  $txtA = $_POST["TextA"];
  $txtB = $_POST["TextB"];

  if(isset($txtB) && !isset($txtA)){
    $textB=$txtB*0.4;
    $Total=$textB;
  }elseif(isset($txtA) && !isset($txtB)){
    $textA=$txtA*0.4;
    $Total=$textA;
  }
  //&& == AND
  if(isset($txtA) && isset($txtB)){
    $textA=$txtA*0.65;
    $textB=$txtB*0.35;
    $Total=$textA + $textB;
  }
  ?>
```